# Can I export a prop based on another condition in sveltekit?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I have a component with both images and text.

```
<script lang="ts">
/** Import pacakges */

/** Props */
export let align: 'left' | 'center' = 'left';
export let bgColor: 'bg-primary' | 'bg-secondary' | 'bg-offwhite' = 'bg-offwhite'
export let hasImage: boolean = false;
export let imageAlign: 'left' | 'right' = 'left';



</script>
```

I want to export a prop ***imgSrc*** only if the hasImage property is true. Is it possible? Are there any other methods to achieve this?

Comment: You should not use `/** ... */` for comment sections, by the way, if that is in your actual code. The `/** Props */` is applied as documentation to the `align` property. Should be `// Props` if anything (wouldn't add that, it's pretty obvious where imports and props are).

Answer (score 1):

You *have* to always export the property, as exports have to appear at the top level.

The only thing you can try to do is adjust the types. There is a way to type all properties via defining a `$$Props` type but I have not been able to make that work, as it does not resolve unions correctly.

You can introduce generics however and infer the type of other properties based on the resolved generic type. [This comment](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/442#issuecomment-1278507804) on the feedback issue pointed me towards this approach:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    type HasImage = $$Generic<boolean | undefined>;

    // other props...

    export let hasImage: HasImage = false as HasImage;
    export let imgSrc: Exclude<HasImage, undefined> extends true ? string : never;
</script>
```

Usage examples:

```html
<Component hasImage imgSrc="x" />
<Component hasImage={false} imgSrc="x" /> <!-- Error -->
<Component hasImage={true} imgSrc="x" />
<Component imgSrc="x" /> <!-- Error -->
```

The errors are:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'. ts(2322)

[RFC for the generics feature](https://github.com/sveltejs/rfcs/pull/38)